# Disable vertical scroll in WKWebview when scrolling down in top of View

Tags: swift, scrollview, wkwebview

How to disable vertical scroll view when user swiping down finger from top of view like on the screen below?

[image]

Don't need that code,

```
self.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

because it blocs all scrolling.

We also need to use vertical scroll view,

[image]

but without the gray box that appears when the user has gone up the page. How to block this moment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable bouncing

```
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```